# How to set case insensitive regexp for validationtextbox inside data-dojo-props

Tags: regex, dojo

I'm using dijit validation textboxes for one of my forms and need to setup a regular expresssion that would allow either a "n/a" value or a URL. 
I have the regular expression working, but it does not accept uppercase values. 
Does anyone knows how could you do that through the data-dojo-props, or would I need to add a custom validator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

tried something similar to this?

```
new ValidationTextBox({
    regExp: new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]*") // short form: /[a-zA-Z]*/
});
```

It will accept any letters a through z in either case.

As a markup attribute it would look like this:

```
<div 
  data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" 
  data-dojo-props="regExp: /[a-zA-Z]*/, invalidMessage: 'Failed to validate'"
></div>
```